# MSSQL getting Argument data type datetime is invalid for argument 1 of substring function even IF EXISTS is false

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write SQL to convert a `varchar` to `datetime` if the column exists and it is a varchar but I keep getting this error:

> Argument data type datetime is invalid for argument 1 of substring function.

My update and alter should only run if the column exists and is a varchar.

```
IF EXISTS (
select 1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'LZS'
AND TABLE_NAME='TBDLZL2760_FOAB369I_RAT_TYP_OPL'
AND COLUMN_NAME ='SENEST_OPDAT'
AND lower(DATA_TYPE)='varchar')
BEGIN

UPDATE LZS.TBDLZL2760_FOAB369I_RAT_TYP_OPL
SET SENEST_OPDAT = 
   CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(SENEST_OPDAT,1,4) >= '1753' THEN
        SUBSTRING(SENEST_OPDAT,1,10)+' '+REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SENEST_OPDAT,12,8),'.',':')+'.'+
        CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(SENEST_OPDAT,21,3) = '999' THEN '998' ELSE SUBSTRING(SENEST_OPDAT,21,3) END
   ELSE '1753-01-01 '+REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SENEST_OPDAT,12,8),'.',':')+'.'+
        CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(SENEST_OPDAT,21,3) = '999' THEN '998' ELSE SUBSTRING(SENEST_OPDAT,21,3) END
    END

    ALTER TABLE LZS.TBDLZL2760_FOAB369I_RAT_TYP_OPL
   ALTER COLUMN SENEST_OPDAT DATETIME NOT NULL;
END;
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: This is a compile error, the parser is seeing that `SUBSTRING` has a `datetime` value as it's first parameter in the batch and so the *entire* batch is not run.

Comment: Run the UPDATE and ALTER TABLE in a dynamic SQL, this will allow to "latebind" and avoid the error